# How do I extend an existing partion to add more space to it?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

Is it possible to add the unallocated space to extend the existing partition ?
Please see image below ?

My machine is a dual boot system with Windows 10 and Ubuntu and single 1 TB HDD. The unallocated space has been claimed from Windows by shrinking the C drive. 
I cannot add a new partition since I already have 4 partitions.

Any pointer to already published articles will also help.

[image: Disk Partition]

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with a few steps:

1. Move `sda3` to the left, the unallocated space will be adjacent to the extended partition `sda4` then.
2. Resize the extended partition `sda4` on it's left side, the unallocated space will be inside the extended partion then.
3. In the unallocated space in the extended partition you could create a logical partition or you could move `sda5`, `sda6` and `sda7` to the left and finally resize `sda8` (I would recommend to create a logical partition, so you don't need to move so many partitions which will be time consuming).

Remind that you have to do this while booted from live-USB. It's also best to have reliable backups.